# How to create 0..1-1 relationship in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a problem trying to correctly configure a relationship in EF. I have used EF code first to generate classes from an existing database. The first table holds a list of instructions, the second holds a record of the state that each instruction is in.

Tables (simplified):

```
Instruction
-----------
InstructionID
CurrentInstructionStateHistoryID

InstructionStateHistory
-----------------------
InstructionStateHistoryID
InstructionID
State
```

So you can see that there are **two** relationships between the tables - a 1-many relationship based on InstructionID, which I'm not interested in, and have therefore deleted the properties for. The second relationship is based on the CurrentInstructionStateHistoryID property, which points to the "current" state of the instruction.

The classes are as follows:

```
public partial class Instruction
{
    [Key]
    public int InstructionID { get; set; }

    public int? CurrentInstructionStateHistoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual CurrentInstructionStateHistory InstructionStateHistory { get; set; }

}

public partial class InstructionStateHistory
{
    [Key]
    public int InstructionStateHistoryID { get; set; }

    public int InstructionID { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    public virtual Instruction tblInstruction { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the fluent API setup to define the relationship:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<InstructionStateHistory>()
        .HasRequired(e => e.tblInstruction)
        .WithOptional(e => e.CurrentInstructionStateHistory);
```

So, it all compiles and runs. But when I get to a bit of code like this:

```
    Instruction instruction = await _dal.InstructionRepository.Find(claimID);
    InstructionStateHistory history = i.CurrentInstructionStateHistory;
```

I can see that the instruction is populated correctly, let's say the Id is 1234. When I examine the InstructionStateHistory object, what I *want* to see is that it's InstructionID is 1234, but instead what I see is that it's **InstructionStateHistoryID**, i.e. is's **primary key**, is 1234 and that it's related to a completely different instruction.
Somehow I need to tell EF that Instruction.CurrentInstructionStateHistoryID links to InstructionStateHistory.InstructionStateHistoryID.
I've tried many combinations of data annotations and fluent setup but have been unable to find a combination that actually works, either I get the above result or a runtime error. Any help gratefully accepted!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like EF just can't handle this case, so the solution was to forget the concept of a "current" InstructionStateHistory. Instead I added a date field to the InstructionStateHistory table, and then changed the Instruction class to have a regular collection property as follows:

```
public virtual ICollection<InstructionStateHistory> InstructionStateHistories{ get; set; }
```

Then when I need the "current" state I just query the colection, sort by date and take the latest one.